# How Multiple Query in datagridview using Dapper with database MS-ACCESS in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, dapper

I have three MS-Access files with different paths. How can I query multiple with dapper from list/model to datagridview.

Please Guide Me.

Thanks

Info path from MS-ACCESS files

```
TABLEA = D:\TABLEA.accdb
TABLEB = Z:\DATA\Malfin 07\TABLEB.accdb
TABLEC = Z:\DATA\Malfin D2\TABLEC.accdb
```

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString)
            Using data = conn.QueryMultiple("select * from User", Nothing)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
Public Class User
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property FIRSTNAME() As String
    Public Property LASTNAME() As String
End Class
```

TABLEA

Table Name : User

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST1000 | 1000TEST |
| 2 | TEST2000 | 2000TEST |

TABLEB

Table Name : User

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST3000 | 3000TEST |
| 2 | TEST4000 | 4000TEST |

TABLEC

Table Name : User

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST5000 | 5000TEST |
| 2 | TEST6000 | 6000TEST |

Desired Result in datagridview

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
| --- | --- |
| TEST1000 | 1000TEST |
| TEST2000 | 2000TEST |
| TEST3000 | 3000TEST |
| TEST4000 | 4000TEST |
| TEST5000 | 5000TEST |
| TEST6000 | 6000TEST |

Comment: You're trying to query three Access databases at once. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @PalleDue , What is the reason you say impossible but from the answer below it gets the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think QueryMultiple works in this way.

Either create three results set and UNION or Concat them:

```
CONST constrA = "..."
CONST constrB = "..."
CONST constrC = "..."

FUNCTION GetUsers(constr AS STRING) AS IENUMERABLE(OF User)
    USING con AS oledbconnection = NEW oledbconnection(constr)
        RETURN con.query(OF User)("SELECT * FROM [User]")
    END USING
END FUNCTION

SUB FORM_LOAD
    users_datagridview.datasource = GetUsers(constrA).UNION(GetUsers(constrB)).UNION(GetUsers(constrC)).TOLIST
END SUB
```

or add tables from B and C database to the A database as a linked-table so you can union them in a single query:

```
CONST constrA = "..."

FUNCTION GetAllUsers() AS IENUMERABLE(OF User)
    USING con As oledbconnection = NEW oledbconnection(constrA)
        RETURN con.query(OF User)("(SELECT * FROM [User]) UNION (SELECT * FROM User_B) UNION (SELECT * FROM User_C)")
    END USING
END FUNCTION

SUB FORM_LOAD
    users_datagridview.datasource = GetAllUsers.TOLIST
END SUB
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer went perfectly. First I have an error `syntax error in from clause` but I renamed the `User` table to `Users` perhaps because reserved words in Access

Comment: Glad to hear that, and thanks for your kind response. I edited the code and add [ ] around User.

Comment: If I make with each sql for each access file is it possible with the first answer option from you

Comment: @pret : Sorry, your question is somehow vague to me. As already mentioned by Palle Due, dapper queries work on a single connection, and therefore a single database, at a time. In the first approach, actually 3 result sets from 3 separate databases are unioned to make a single result set. And, a separate connection is used for each database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and later I explain if I make a recent post